# Getting crash when I am trying to fetch the data from SQlite table

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, crash

When I try to fetch the data from SQlite table it is getting crashed and prints the details as below in console. Can any one tell how to resolve these kind of crashes.

```
thread #11: tid = 0xa162, 0x0162b03d libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3VdbeHalt + 3693, queue = 'com.org.test, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x32)
    frame #0: 0x0162b03d libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3VdbeHalt + 3693
    frame #1: 0x01626e49 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3VdbeExec + 46521
    frame #2: 0x01596be1 libsqlite3
```

Comment: Please add some code, clairvoyance is not a best tool here.

Comment: Please post a symbolic stack trace the relevant code.